# Example of a reversible Markov chain which has a stationary but non-reversible distribution?

Tags: stochastic-processes

For a Markov chain, I define a reversible distribution to be a distribution wrt which the MC is reversible to. A stationary distribution is defined as a distribution that once reached will stay.
A reversible distribution is a stationary distribution. But not vice versa.

I was wondering if a MC that has a reversible distribution can have a stationary distribution which is not a reversible distribution?

My question comes from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheeger_bound):

> Let $X$ be a finite set and let $K(x,y)$ be the transition probability for a reversible Markov chain on $X$. Assume this chain has stationary distribution $\pi$.

$\pi$ seems to be used as a reversible distribution in the article.
I was wondering why it doesn't say $\pi$ is a distribution wrt which the MC is reversible.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an irreducible Markov chain, a stationary distribution exists if and only if all states are positive recurrent. When this condition is met, the stationary distribution is unique.

Thus, if a Markov chain (reversible or not) is irreducible and has a stationary distribution, this stationary distribution is unique.

If a Markov chain on a finite set is reversible in the sense that $\mu(x)K(x,y)=\mu(y)K(y,x)$ for every $x$ and $y$, for some measure $\mu$, then $\pi=\mu/|\mu|$ is a stationary distribution. Thus, if a Markov chain on a finite set is reversible and irreducible, it has exactly one stationary distribution, which is reversible.

Comment: +1 Thanks! So I guess that Wikipedia article should add: the finite-state reversible MC is additionally irreducible. Can I also guess for a general reversible MC, there might be a stationary distribution which is not reversible?

Comment: It seems to me that this does not answer the op questions. The question was if it is possible for a reversible Markov chain to posses a non-reversible stationary distribution.

Comment: @Adam Please read slowly: "if a Markov chain on a finite set is reversible and irreducible, it has exactly one stationary distribution, which is reversible."

Comment: I am not saying that your answer is wrong, I am just saying that the op question is still open.

Comment: @Adam Yes. And I think this statement is false.

Comment: It seems to me that you say if the MC is reversible and irreducible, then it can not posses a non-reversible stationary distribution because the stationary distribution is unique. But how can you assure that there is no reversible, reducible MC that posses a non reversible stationary distribution?

Comment: @Adam Because I can produce a stationary distribution and it happens to be reversible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25075/discussion-between-adam-and-did).

Comment: @did: In your third paragraph you introduced the assumption that the Markov chain has a finite state space, which was absent from the original question.